# Can i use ksize on memory allocated by vmalloc

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, vmalloc

Can i use ksize on memory allocated by vmalloc.

I know ksize is used to determine the actual amount of memory allocated

So, i wanted to find out whether vmalloc round up allocations and return more memory than requested.

Will the below code works?

```
ptr =vmalloc(1);
printk("I got: %zu bytes of memory\n", ksize(ptr));
vfree(ptr);
```

Comment: According to the documentation, "The caller must guarantee that objp points to a valid object previously allocated with either kmalloc() or kmem_cache_alloc()."

Comment: What is the alternative for it in vmalloc

Comment: I don't think there is an alternative for `vmalloc`, although the size will be rounded up to a multiple of `PAGE_SIZE`.